# Why are changes in a dependency not propagated to the project, which uses it?

Tags: java, maven, gwt, maven-3

I have a mavenized GWT project A, which depends on project B (mavenized GWT module).

When I modify project B (add a diagnostic message, for example), run `mvn install` in B's directory and run project A, the changes in B are not propagated (the diagnostic message, which I added, does not appear in a log file).

`mvn install` on B ends with success. The group, artifact ID and version of the `dependency` tag in A's `pom.xml` are correct.

What could cause the changes in B not be propagated to A?

Comment: Have you tried `mvn clean install` ?

Comment: Yes, I cleaned it several times.

Comment: Is `mvn clean install` sufficient for building a GWT module (isn't something like `mvn clean compile package install` necessary) ?

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko: the Maven lifecycle is linear, and the `install` phase comes after the `package` phase which comes after the `compile` phase. And in case you wonder, the `gwt:compile` goal binds by default (i.e. unless you explicitly configure it otherwise) to the `prepare-package` phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `mvn source:jar install` instead of `mvn install` solved my problem.